# C++ can't display ActiveX control in the dialog CFormView, control variable is NULL

Tags: c++, null, mfc, activex, cview

I use a [SmartGraph](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/atl/smartgraph.aspx) ActiveX control in my project (Visual Studio 2015, MFC, C++). It has been registered successfully. 
I try to fit a dialog with this control into CFormView

MyAppView.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "SmartGraph.h"
#include "afxwin.h"

class CMyAppView : public CFormView
{
protected: // create from serialization only
    CMyAppView();
    DECLARE_DYNCREATE(CMyAppView)

    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };

    CSmartGraph m_Graph; //!!!!! ActiveX control variable
    CButton m_ctrlOK;
....
}
```

MyAppView.cpp:

```
....

void CMyAppView::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CFormView::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDOK, m_ctrlOK);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_SMARTGRAPH1, m_Graph);
}

void CMyAppView::OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CFormView::OnInitialUpdate();
    ResizeParentToFit();

    m_Graph.SetParentWnd(this->m_hWnd);
    m_Graph.SetPlotType(0);
    m_Graph.put_xLable(_T("Time"));
    m_Graph.put_yLable(_T("Amplitude"));
    m_Graph.put_Title(_T("Graph Test"));
}
...
```

So the m_Graph is NULL and SmartGraph isn't displayed in the dialog. At the same time the OK button variable isn't NULL and it is displayed correctly.
What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of this object. m_Graph.CreateControl(...);

Comment: In "SmartGraph.h" there are two methods that return CreateControl(), but in working Demo Project from the author he doesn't use this methonds at all.

Comment: I've tried this method - debug assertion Faled in occsite.cpp Line 212

Comment: Thew working demo may us a dialog template were the control is created implicit in the template... Anyhow you need to create the object!

Comment: @xMRi: m_Graph's control should be created by DDX_Control, as far as I remember. To Nika_Rika: Put a breakpoint on DDX_Control, step through it, and see if it has been created successfully (i.e. m_Graph.m_hWnd is not NULL) and if not, try to determine the cause there.